# Why only PUTNOW works with bind time or bind cron in eggdrop tcl?

Tags: tcl, blowfish, eggdrop

I made a script that says "Hello World" every 10 minutes. I use *bind time* or *bind cron*. But it only works with "putnow". It does not work with *puthelp* or *putserv*. Why?

- I can see Message 2 and Message 3 (in pm), but not Message 1

Here is the code:

```
bind cron - {*/5 * * * *} reminder
#bind time - "?5 * * * *" reminder

proc reminder {min hour day month year} {
    putquick "PRIVMSG #BobsChan :Hello World - Message 1"
    puts "This goes in the logs- Message 2"
    putnow "PRIVMSG funkyBob :Hello World - Message 3"
}
```

Update: I figured out that it has something to do with the blowfish encryption. I disabled silent mode of blowfish in tcleggdrop_mcps_sitesettings.ini and now eggdrop gives me this message every time gets triggerd: "eggdrop reply blocked since command was issued in plaintext; this bot only responds to encrypted commands". If I bind the same proc to a pub trigger, it works just fine though.

Comment: Sorry, I formulated the code wrongly. $ was supposed to be #. It is a working code. If I trigger that proc with bind pub it works, I can see Message 1.

Comment: This is all rather specific to the eggdrop application; something subtle is going on and I don't know enough to help (I do general `tcl` help instead).